# TSQL CONVERT + CASE functions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm running into a problem with my query below. I'm using case to input a value of `--` when a field is left blank. I can update the value of `--` to `0` instead but i'm still getting an error message when the query executes, I suspect it's because the addition cannot complete with null/blank values.

I'm having the same problem with UPDATE statements.

INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO AME_GridF18
(SubmissionID,TS_Added,ProjectNumber,ProjectName,TypeofWork,Mile,Toll,Park,MonRT,MonOT,TuesRT,TuesOT,WedsRT,WedsOT,ThursRT,ThursOT,FriRT,FriOT,Saturday,Sunday,Total)
VALUES
(
'[querystring:SubmissionID]'
,'[DateTime:Now]'
,case when '[ProjectNumber]' = '' then '--' else '[ProjectNumber]' end
,case when '[ProjectName]' = '' then '--' else '[ProjectName]' end
,case when '[TypeofWork]' = '' then '--' else '[TypeofWork]' end
,case when '[Mile]' = '' then '--' else '[Mile]' end
,case when '[Toll]' = '' then '--' else '[Toll]' end
,case when '[Park]' = '' then '--' else '[Park]' end
,case when '[MonRT]' = '' then '--' else '[MonRT]' end
,case when '[MonOT]' = '' then '--' else '[MonOT]' end
,case when '[TuesRT]' = '' then '--' else '[TuesRT]' end
,case when '[TuesOT]' = '' then '--' else '[TuesOT]' end
,case when '[WedsRT]' = '' then '--' else '[WedsRT]' end
,case when '[WedsOT]' = '' then '--' else '[WedsOT]' end
,case when '[ThursRT]' = '' then '--' else '[ThursRT]' end
,case when '[ThursOT]' = '' then '--' else '[ThursOT]' end
,case when '[FriRT]' = '' then '--' else '[FriRT]' end
,case when '[FriOT]' = '' then '--' else '[FriOT]' end
,case when '[Saturday]' = '' then '--' else '[Saturday]' end
,case when '[Sunday]' = '' then '--' else '[Sunday]' end
,CONVERT(Varchar, ([MonRT] + [MonOT] + [TuesRT] + [TuesOT] + [WedsRT] + [WedsOT] + [ThursRT] + [ThursOT] + [FriRT] + [FriOT] + [Saturday] + [Sunday])
))
```

UPDATE:

```
UPDATE AME_GridF18
SET
SubmissionID = '[querystring:SubmissionID]',
TS_Added = '[DateTime:Now]',
ProjectNumber = '[ProjectNumber]',
ProjectName = '[ProjectName]',
TypeofWork = '[TypeofWork]',
Mile = '[Mile]',
Toll = '[Toll]',
Park = '[Park]',
MonRT = '[MonRT]',
MonOT = '[MonOT]',
TuesRT = '[TuesRT]',
TuesOT = '[TuesOT]',
WedsRT = '[WedsRT]',
WedsOT = '[WedsOT]',
ThursRT = '[ThursRT]',
ThursOT = '[ThursOT]',
FriRT = '[FriRT]',
FriOT = '[FriOT]',
Saturday = '[Saturday]',
Sunday = '[Sunday]',
Total = CONVERT(Varchar, ([MonRT] + [MonOT] + [TuesRT] + [TuesOT] + [WedsRT] + [WedsOT] + [ThursRT] + [ThursOT] + [FriRT] + [FriOT] + [Saturday] + [Sunday]))
WHERE ID = [ID]
```

Comment: Are you sure you understand the syntax you use? It does not make any sense at all.

Comment: The field `Total` should be the `SUM` of Mon,Tues,Weds,etc... I believe the syntax is correct for this no?

Comment: everything in `[Token]` format in the query will be replaced with a user's input on a webform. So all Mon,Tues,Weds,etc.. will have `integers` but in the case one of them is left empty the `+` operator i think is getting thrown off.

Comment: Each case expression would need to be a select `(select case when '[Mile]' = '' then '--' else '[Mile]' end')` **BUT** why store `--` when you don't need to? **AND**you CANNOT store `--` in number columns. I suggest you provide the DDL of your table so that we know what data types you are dealing with.

Comment: also, provide the **complete** ERROR MESSAGE (do this for any question about an error)

Comment: You said: _"everything in [Token] format in the query will be replaced with a user's input on a webform"_ - it looks to me like you may well have a very serious SQL injection issue that you should be thinking about *before* trying to fix this error message [#parameterize](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) - and please supply your error message so we can help with that problem

Comment: `'[ProjectNumber]'` is a **string**, not a column, which just isn't equal to the string `'--'`.  In any case, you can only store strings in string columns which makes the call to `CONVERT` pointless. Just concatenate the columns

Comment: BTW storing numbers in string columns is a very, very bad idea. If you want to store numerical data and be able to process it, use the *correct* numerical type. Either one of the integer types, or `numeric(..)`. Don't use float, or the next question will be "why can't I get exact results`

Comment: Okay, I can switch to integer data types for my day's as those will always be numbers.

Comment: I just need to convert the days OT and RT not the other strings. I'm going to try and switch those columns to integer and see if that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I used `CASE` is because if the user did not specify a value for any of the weekdays it needed to result in `0`. My problem was during the calculation on `INSERT` if the user left any inputs blank the SQL would run like: `1+1++1+1` instead of `1+1+0+1+1` and would throw an error.

I ended up switching all my week fields to Integer and setup an auto-calculation on the table itself to calculate the total field and just disregarded that on my `INSERT` statement, which works as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're trying to do this?

```
DECLARE
@SubmissionID INT
,@TS_Added SMALLDATETIME
,@ProjectNumber VARCHAR(MAX)
,@ProjectName VARCHAR(MAX)
,@TypeofWork VARCHAR(MAX)
,@Mile FLOAT
,@Toll FLOAT
,@Park FLOAT
,@MonRT FLOAT
,@MonOT FLOAT
,@TuesRT FLOAT
,@TuesOT FLOAT
,@WedsRT FLOAT
,@WedsOT FLOAT
,@ThursRT FLOAT
,@ThursOT FLOAT
,@FriRT FLOAT
,@FriOT FLOAT
,@Saturday FLOAT
,@Sunday FLOAT
,@Total FLOAT

INSERT INTO AME_GridF18
(
SubmissionID
,TS_Added
,ProjectNumber
,ProjectName
,TypeofWork
,Mile
,Toll
,Park
,MonRT
,MonOT
,TuesRT
,TuesOT
,WedsRT
,WedsOT
,ThursRT
,ThursOT
,FriRT
,FriOT
,Saturday
,Sunday
,Total
)
SELECT
@SubmissionID
,GETDATE()
,CASE WHEN ISNULL(@ProjectNumber,'') = '' THEN '--' ELSE @ProjectNumber END
,CASE WHEN ISNULL(@ProjectName,'') = '' THEN '--' ELSE @ProjectName END
,CASE WHEN ISNULL(@TypeofWork,'') = '' THEN '--' ELSE @TypeofWork END
,CASE WHEN ISNULL(@Mile,0) =0 THEN '--' ELSE CAST(@Mile AS VARCHAR(30)) END
,CASE WHEN ISNULL(@Toll,0) = 0 THEN '--' ELSE CAST(@Toll AS VARCHAR(30)) END
,CASE WHEN ISNULL(@Park,0) = 0 THEN '--' ELSE CAST(@Park AS VARCHAR(30)) END
,CASE WHEN ISNULL(@MonRT,0) = 0 THEN '--' ELSE CAST(@MonRT AS VARCHAR(30)) END
,CASE WHEN ISNULL(@MonOT,0) = 0 THEN '--' ELSE CAST(@MonOT AS VARCHAR(30)) END
,CASE WHEN ISNULL(@TuesRT,0) = 0 THEN '--' ELSE CAST(@TuesRT AS VARCHAR(30)) END
,CASE WHEN ISNULL(@TuesOT,0) = 0 THEN '--' ELSE CAST(@TuesOT AS VARCHAR(30)) END
,CASE WHEN ISNULL(@WedsRT,0) = 0 THEN '--' ELSE CAST(@WedsRT AS VARCHAR(30)) END
,CASE WHEN ISNULL(@WedsOT,0) = 0 THEN '--' ELSE CAST(@WedsOT AS VARCHAR(30)) END
,CASE WHEN ISNULL(@ThursRT,0) = 0 THEN '--' ELSE CAST(@ThursRT AS VARCHAR(30)) END
,CASE WHEN ISNULL(@ThursOT,0) = 0 THEN '--' ELSE CAST(@ThursOT AS VARCHAR(30)) END
,CASE WHEN ISNULL(@FriRT,0) = 0 THEN '--' ELSE CAST(@FriRT AS VARCHAR(30)) END
,CASE WHEN ISNULL(@FriOT,0) = 0 THEN '--' ELSE CAST(@FriOT AS VARCHAR(30)) END
,CASE WHEN ISNULL(@Saturday,0) = 0 THEN '--' ELSE CAST(@Saturday AS VARCHAR(30)) END
,CASE WHEN ISNULL(@Sunday,0) = 0 THEN '--' ELSE CAST(@Sunday AS VARCHAR(30)) END
,CAST((@MonRT + @MonOT + @TuesRT + @TuesOT + @WedsRT + @WedsOT + @ThursRT + @ThursOT + @FriRT + @FriOT + @Saturday + @Sunday) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
```

Comment: Using float is a problem itself as it leads to imprecise results. That's why `numeric(...)` is used in most cases

Comment: The declaration of variables above are just for assumptions since we don't know the variable types that is being used for his script.

Comment: The following gets me -- for all values on insert.